# Cannot run any Clipboard Managers in my system

Tags: xfce, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I’ve been using Ubuntu for a while now, but for some reason I can’t get any clipboard manager to work on my system. Everything else works fine, like installing and using new apps, but clipboard managers just don’t. I used to have **Clipman** and it worked great. But then one day it just stopped working. It disappeared from my panel and whenever I try to launch it manually with `xfce4-clipman`, I get a bunch of errors.

```
** (xfce4-clipman:4446): WARNING **: 19:13:41.327: Unable to register GApplication: An object is already exported for the interface org.gtk.Application at /org/xfce/clipman

(xfce4-clipman:4446): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:13:41.327: g_application_get_is_remote: assertion 'application->priv->is_registered' failed

(xfce4-clipman:4446): GLib-WARNING **: 19:13:41.327: g_set_application_name() called multiple times

** (xfce4-clipman:4446): WARNING **: 19:14:42.058: Status Icon is not embedded

(xfce4-clipman:4446): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:14:42.059: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

I have tried various solutions online to fix **Clipman**, such as changing the autostart session, using `killall`, removing and reinstalling all the packages related to it, using `pkill` and `rm ~/.local/share/xfce4/clipman/history`. However, none of them worked. I also installed **Clipit** but it didn’t work either. When I launched Clipit manually, it showed the following errors

```
** (clipit:4415): WARNING **: 19:12:53.754: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>H' failed!


** (clipit:4415): WARNING **: 19:12:53.754: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>A' failed!


** (clipit:4415): WARNING **: 19:12:53.754: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>P' failed!


** (clipit:4415): WARNING **: 19:12:53.754: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>F' failed!


** (clipit:4415): WARNING **: 19:12:53.754: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>O' failed!
```

and went on....

I also tried **Diodon** but it wouldn’t launch at all, neither from the terminal nor by clicking on it.

Comment: Are either of these two apps known to work with your unstated version of Ubuntu and the DE you are using?

Comment: The versions are 22.04 LTS and xfce is 4.16 and I'm pretty sure they are compatible with these

Comment: The question is missing release details (*this is a Question and Answer site and not a forum, please add additional details or changes to your question*).  Xubuntu/Xfce has a working clipboard; but you mention Ubuntu so I wonder if your system was a Ubuntu one where you added parts of Xfce but not all of Xubuntu/Xfce thus your issue but it's unclear to me from your question (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/jammy/release/xubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest is what is included). I'd look for clues in what changes were made the session before your clipman stopped working (ie. logs)